# Wrong Persian glyphs in default persian font for Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic Minotaur

Tags: fonts, 23.10

Luckily, the latest version of Ubuntu OS (23.10 Mantic Minotaur) has resolved the issue with the default font by switching it to Noto-Sans Arabic, which also supports Persian. However, there remains an issue with the Persian Peh glyph, as evident in the screenshot.

[image]

As observed, the initial form of the Persian Peh is incorrect, while its middle form is accurate. I verified this on the Google Fonts test page by copying the text from my text editor, and it functioned without any issues.

[image]

I’m curious to find out if anyone else has encountered this issue and what steps can be taken to resolve it. Can anyone provide some guidance?

### #UPDATE

I checked characters map and here is a screenshot of that. You can see that all forms of Peh are wrong except the middle form!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem using newer version of `NotoSansArabic-Regular` from google repos. The NotoSansArabic-Regular version that is used in Ubuntu 23.10 was from 2020.

I copied over the `NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf` from downloaded repo to the folder `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto` using this command:

```
sudo cp /home/<username>/Downloads/Noto_Sans_Arabic/static/NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/
```

then refreshed the cache for the fonts:

```
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

then I logged out and logged in again and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with Noto Sans Arabic. We can fix the problem by switching to Noto Naskh Arabic, which is what my Firefox uses instead of Noto Sans Arabic for the correctly displayed part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pe_(Persian_letter) . Let's adjust this font setting:

## gedit

1. Open preferences. Observe the i‘jām upside down.

[image: gedit preferences, bad font]

2. Uncheck "Use the system fixed width font (Ubuntu Mono 13)" in "Fonts & Colors".

[image: fonts & colors preferences]

3. Select "Noto Naskh Arabic Regular". Don't select the broken "Noto Sans Arabic". The i‘jām will now be correctly displayed.

[image: gedit selecting Noto Naskh Arabic, good font]

## gnome-text-editor

1. Open preferences. Observe the i‘jām upside down.

[image: gnome-text-editor preferences, bad font]

2. Scroll down and turn on "Custom Font".
   [image: gnome-text-editor custom font]
3. Select "Noto Naskh Arabic Regular". Don't select the broken "Noto Sans Arabic". The i‘jām will now be correctly displayed.

[image: gnome-text-editor selecting Noto Naskh Arabic, good font]

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't help. Turning on the Custom Font in Gnome Editor uses the monospaced font that looks like the old fashioned font of the Ubuntu. Besides browsers like FF and Chrome in it's default format still use noto with wrong glyphs.

Comment: @MahyarPasarzangene Does setting the font to "Noto Naskh Arabic" work? My FF was using that font instead of the broken Noto Sans Arabic whenever it was displaying Peh properly